# How to connect to a MySQL database on another domain using php?

Tags: php, mysqli

this code cannot connect another domain database , I have tried..

```
<?php 
$con_mail = mysqli_connect("domain","user","pass","db"); 
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
?>
```

my error is

> "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'joojmail.com' (110)"

Comment: and the error message that you get is..?

Comment: <?php 
$con_mail = mysqli_connect("domain","user","pass","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 ?>

Comment: my error is "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'joojmail.com' (110)"

Comment: domian or database?

Comment: Put that information in your question Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41038231/edit) link under the question

Comment: database @  Shanu k k

Comment: Looks like the access is blocked by a firewall, which is not surprising, or that the server does not listen to remote connections.

Comment: may be mysql is running host name differs.

Answer (score 1):

A frequent security setting used in SQL Server is to only allow local access.

If you can connect to a local database but another domain does not work I would think your access is blocked by the server.

Comment: cannot understand

Comment: MYSQL User accounts have 2 parts 1) the userid 2) the place(s) where they are allowed to connect FROM. If the account you are using does not allow REMOTE connection you cannot connect remotely

Comment: Try to connect to the database with a desktop app first, something like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). Then you know if it generally works.